# Placing vector in After Effects results in grey box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-after-effects

In After Effects (CC2017), when I import a project from Illustrator (CC2017), place it on the timeline and select "Create shapes from vector layer", it creates a grey rectangle. There is no opacity on any layer in the Illustrator project and none in AE.

I've provided some screenshots below to show the object in AI and how it looks after being placed in AE.

Does anyone have prior experience with this issue or have any idea on what could be causing this result?

[image: Illustrator project]

[image: AE project]

Comment: We need more details. Is the Illustrator project actually vector? Can we see a screenshot with your layers and objects?

Comment: I added the images to the original post. Don't know ho to add to this comment.

Comment: Your Illustrator screenshot clearly shows a *raster* image and zero vector content. I'm not an AE user, but if you are expecting AE to read vector data from that AI file.. there is no vector data. Merely opening or saving a raster image with Illustrator doesn't make it vector. I think you need to describe the workflow a bit more, from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my end! I hope this helps someone else with the same issue. The problem somehow is glitched when you check the "continuous rasterize" in the composition and each individual AE illustrator layer inside that composition. What did it for me, is leave the CR on inside the composition, but turn it off on the comp itself. Hope this helps!!

-N

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to avoid using gradients and other effects on your AI file as After Effects does not decode the color combination thus turning them into gray. Make sure your images are plane colors in AI, once you convert to shape layer, you can apply gradient in AE.

Hope this helps!